# How to show these linear maps span the symmetric linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

In trying to prove that the space of all symmetric linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to itself form a linear subspace, which I'll call $S$, of all general such maps, of dimension $d=n(n+1)/2$, I am trying to show that a certain set of linear maps span that $S$. I shall describe that set.

Firstly, having chosen the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$, $\{b_k\}$, let $T_{ij}$, with $i \neq j$, be the linear map that sends every
$b_k$ to zero, expect when $k=j,i$, in which case it swaps them. Further, let $S_i$ send all the members of the basis to zero expect for the i-th one, which it sends to itself.

I tried to determine a linear combination given an arbitrary $A\in S$, but I was unable to. I tried to use the defining property of symmetric maps (that it "commutes" in the inner product) where I used the canonical basis, but I arrived nowhere. Can anyone direct me on how to do this?

Comment: Is it important to you to go via this basis? I think it'd be simpler to show that the space in question is closed under addition/scaling if the ultimate goal is to show that it is a subspace.

Comment: @einar that it is a subspace I have already demonstrated; what I specifically want now is how to show that it has that specific dimension

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unsophisticated, but since the space of linear operators on $\mathbb R^n$ is isomorphic to the space of $n\times n$ matrices, and the space of self-adjoint operators is isomorphic to the space of symmetric matrices, you could make a proof about matrices.

First we add the restriction that $i\leq j$, since $T_{i,j} = T_{j,i}$ are linearly dependent, so half of those must be excluded. In this notation, $S_i = T_{i,i}$. The list of matrices $A_{i,j} = \mathcal M(T_{i,j})$ with $i, j \in 1,\ldots ,n$ and $i \leq j$ makes a basis for the space of symmetric matrices.

There are $n(n+1)/2$ of these as you say; the $n$ $(i,i)$ matrices that are all zeros except for a 1 in the $(i,i)$ entry, and the $(n^2 - n)/2$ $(i,j)$ entries that are all zeros except for 1s in the two entries $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$. Any symmetric matrix can be written as a linear combination of these matrices:
$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 
    b_{11} & b_{12} & \dots  & b_{1n}\\
    b_{12}  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & b_{(n-1)n}  \\
    b_{1n} & \dots  & b_{(n-1)n} & b_{nn} 
    \end{bmatrix}\\
  = b_{11}A_{1,1} + b_{12}A_{1,2} + \ldots + b_{1n}A_{1,n} + \ldots + b_{(n-1)n}A_{n-1,n} + b_{nn}A_{n,n},
 $$
so the list spans the space, and the only way to get the zero matrix is to take each $b_{ij}$ = 0, so it is a basis.

For complex matrices you need a bigger basis: you need a set of $n(n-1)/2$ matrices with $i$ in the $(i,j)$ entry and $-i$ in the $(j,i)$ entry, or something similar.